# How to have the Input field save the value

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, state

I have a simple freeform text box and i am attempting to make a post to the api to save the users input. The parent component is a class component and the child a functional. I am having an issue making the field hold the value when I move to another page and back can someone show me where Im going wrong here?

vitals.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import VitalsEditor from "./VitalsEditor";
import BlockSection from "./BlockSection";
import { Input } from "reactstrap"

export default function Vitals(props) {
  const vitals = props.vitals || {};
  const requiredVitals = ["height", "weight", "heartRate"];
  const visitType = props.visitType
  const [showErrorsFor, setShowErrorsFor] = useState([]);
  const [vitalsInput, setVitalsInput] = useState("")

 useEffect(() => {
    setShowErrorsFor(props.requiredFields);
  }, [props.showRequiredFieldErrors]);

const onVitalsChange = (e) => {
    setVitalsInput(e.target.value)
  }

let content;

if (visitType === "nursing_home"){
   content = <Input 
   type="textarea"
   name="vitals"
   onChange={onVitalsChange}
   vitalsInput={vitalsInput}
   value={vitalsInput}
    />
  }
  else {
    content = (
      <View vitals={vitals} isClinicalServices={props.isClinicalServices} />
    );
  }

  return <BlockSection title="Vitals">{content}</BlockSection>;
}
```

Patientinfo.js

```
export default class PatientInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCatalog();
  }

render() {
 const updateVitals = () => {
     let vitals = this.props.vitalsInput 
      api.Encounters.vitalsUpdate({vitals: vitals})
    }
    return (
 {visitType === "nursing_home" && 
        <InfoEditWrapper
        readOnly={true}
        data={""}
        title={"vitals"}
      >
        <Vitals
          visitType={this.props.visitType}
          onChange={updateVitals}
          vitalsInput={this.props.vitalsInput}
          value={this.props.vitalsInput}
        />
      </InfoEditWrapper>
        }
);
  }
}
```

Im having a hard time understanding how to make the value inputed save to the state and to post to the api. The api accepts a json body similar to what im passing it
`{ "vitals": "This is a long string of reported vitals" }` 
the PatientInfo component is passed its props from another component
Encounter.js

```
<PatientInfo
                      medicalProfile={profile}
                      medicalIntake={intake}
                      testResult={testResult}
                      currentUser={currentUser}
                      visitType={visitType}
                      patient={patient}
                      visitType={visitType}
                      note={note}
                      onNoteUpdate={this.onNoteUpdate}
                      onProfileChanged={this.onProfileChanged}
                      onProfileSave={this.onProfileSave}
                      onIntakeChanged={this.onIntakeChanged}
                      onIntakeSave={this.onIntakeSave}
                      onRemoveUnsavedSection={this.onRemoveUnsavedSection}
                      unsavedSections={this.state.unsavedSections}
                    />
```

Really any feedback would be great thank you!

Comment: can you share where you import Userinfo.js and which props you pass?

Comment: Yes I'd mislabeled the patientinfo component but now im showing all the props it is passed from its parent